# Rails create inline time dropdown using zurb foundation in form

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, select, zurb-foundation

Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm trying to create an inline selector for hours:minutes using Zurb Foundation in Rails.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-3 columns"><%= f.label :preptime, class: "inline-right" %></div>
    <div class="small-3 columns time_select"><%= f.time_select :preptime, {:default => {:hour => '0', :minute => '15'}} %></div>
</div>
```

I created a custom class to try to fix it based on another post here.

```
.time_select{
display: inline;
color: blue;
}
```

When I include the code here in the form, I get

```
Preptime     00
:
15
```

rather than the inline selector I expect.

Here is the generated html:

```
        <div class="row"><div class="small-3 columns"><label class="inline-right" for="recipe_yield">Yield</label></div>
    <div class="small-9 columns"><input type="text" value="4.0" name="recipe[yield]" id="recipe_yield" /></div></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-3 columns"><label class="inline-right" for="recipe_preptime">Preptime</label></div>
        <div class="small-3 columns time_select"><input type="hidden" id="recipe_preptime_1i" name="recipe[preptime(1i)]" value="2000" />
<input type="hidden" id="recipe_preptime_2i" name="recipe[preptime(2i)]" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" id="recipe_preptime_3i" name="recipe[preptime(3i)]" value="1" />
<select id="recipe_preptime_4i" name="recipe[preptime(4i)]">
    <option value="00" selected="selected">00</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    ... (options removed)
    <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
 : <select id="recipe_preptime_5i" name="recipe[preptime(5i)]">
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    ... (options removed)
    <option value="59">59</option>
</select>

    </div>
    </div>
```